# How to force NHibernate not to update all objects in collection

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, orm

How to force NHibernate not to generate UPDATE for each element in collection if I change only one element of that collection. Here it is:

```
internal class Master
{
    private int _id;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ISet<Slave> Slaves { get; set; }

    public Master()
    {
        Slaves = new HashedSet<Slave>();
    }
}

internal class Slave
{
    private int _id;

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
<class name="nHibernateTutorials.Slave, nHibernateTutorials" lazy="false">
    <id access="field" name="_id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property access="property" name="Name" column="name"/>
    <many-to-one access="property" name="Master" column="master"/>
</class>

<class name="nHibernateTutorials.Master, nHibernateTutorials" lazy="false">
    <id access="field" name="_id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property access="property" name="Name" column="name"/>
    <set access="property" name="Slaves" cascade="save-update">
        <key column="master"/>
        <one-to-many class="nHibernateTutorials.Slave, nHibernateTutorials"/>
    </set>
</class>
```

Code that updates collection element:

```
Master m = new Master {Name = "Kenny"};

Slave s1 = new Slave { Name = "Cartman", Master = m};
m.Slaves.Add(s1);
Slave s2 = new Slave {Name = "Kyle", Master = m};
m.Slaves.Add(s2);
Slave s3 = new Slave {Name = "Stan", Master = m};
m.Slaves.Add(s3);

DbManager.SaveObject(m);

s1.Name = "Daisy";
DbManager.SaveObject(m);
```

Code in DbManager.SaveObject simply opens new session and uses SaveOrUpdate to update object.

If I change one of the elements from the Slaves collection of master and then try to update master, NHibernate generates SQL for updating all elements in Slaves collection. But I need to update only one element.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing superfluous many-to-one updates.  When you're mapping one-to-many collections, you must choose which side is the owner of the relationship.  In your example, *both* sides of the relationship think they own it!

You need to add an attribute to your set element, with `inverse="true"`.  That directive tells NHibernate not to update the collection from that end of the relationship.

Comment: In this case I should explicitly save changed collection element, but instead I want to save only collection that contains it and get single UPDATE statement for only changed element.

Comment: Can you show the code where you load the entity, make the change and save it?  It sounds like you're maybe reattaching a detached collection.  In that case, NHibernate has no way to track changes and it updates all objects (by default).

Answer (score 0):

Try using access="backfield" instead of access="property".

Comment: check this:
http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/20/how-test-your-mappings-the-ghostbuster.aspx

and this:
http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/02/nhibernate-ghostbuster-version-11.html

Answer (score 0):

You are resaving a transient collection, because Master.Slaves is still the original collection.

This would not happen in a new session.

If you want to update an entity in the same session after saving, you should session.Refresh() that entity. Your DBManager.SaveObject method could do a refresh after save.

```
DbManager.SaveObject<T>( T entity )
{
    session.Save( entity );
    session.Refresh( entity );
}
```