# Why does NHibernate delete and recreate all associations in a collection when I add one item to it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm doing some tests using NHibernate and I currently have two mapped entities, **Orders** and **Products**. As always an **Order** has a collection of **Products**, and I'm mapping this as:

```
<bag name="Products" cascade="all" lazy="true">
  <key column ="Order_ID" />
  <many-to-many class="Product" column="Product_ID" />
</bag>
```

And on the C# side:

```
public virtual IList<Product> Products
{
    get { return _Products; }
    set { _Products = value; }
}
private IList<Product> _Products = new List<Product>();
```

In the case I have one persisted **Order** (John's order) in the database with some items in its **Products** collection (an apple, an orange and a coconut) and I try to add a new item to the collection (a banana) I can see from the SQL output that NHibernate is doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Products_Table (Product_Name, Product_ID) VALUES ('Banana', @Banana_ID)
DELETE FROM Products WHERE Order_ID = @Johns_Order_ID
INSERT INTO Products (Order_ID, Product_ID) VALUES (@Johns_Order_ID, @Apple_ID)
INSERT INTO Products (Order_ID, Product_ID) VALUES (@Johns_Order_ID, @Orange_ID)
INSERT INTO Products (Order_ID, Product_ID) VALUES (@Johns_Order_ID, @Coconut_ID)
INSERT INTO Products (Order_ID, Product_ID) VALUES (@Johns_Order_ID, @Banana_ID)
```

Instead of simply doing something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Products_Table (Product_Name, Product_ID) VALUES ('Banana', @Banana_ID)
INSERT INTO Products (Order_ID, Product_ID) VALUES (@Johns_Order_ID, @Banana_ID)
```

So why does NHibernate delete all associations from the **Products** table to recreate them again when I'm only trying to insert a new product in it? How to avoid it?

Thanks in advance!

PS: I tried to use the **inverse** mapping attribute as suggested in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311849/how-to-force-nhibernate-not-to-update-all-objects-in-collection) but even though the new product gets saved its association with an order doesn't.

**EDIT:**

Here is the code I'm using to modify the products list:

```
Order order = session.Load<Order>(orderId);
order.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "Banana" });
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    session.Update(order);
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for modifying the product list

Comment: Hi, I edited my question to include the code I'm using to modify the products list as you suggested.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's already a similar question on SO: [NHibernate Many-To-Many Is Deleting All Associations Before Inserting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837601/nhibernate-many-to-many-is-deleting-all-associations-before-inserting)

From NHibernate's [documentation](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-collections-taxonomy):

> Bags are the worst case. Since a bag permits duplicate element values
>   and has no index column, no primary key may be defined. NHibernate has
>   no way of distinguishing between duplicate rows. NHibernate resolves
>   this problem by completely removing (in a single DELETE) and
>   recreating the collection whenever it changes. This might be very
>   inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and I'm sorry for not being able to find that similar question myself. Now I switched my mapping to an **idbag** instead of a **bag** and everything is working like a charm!